# how do you manually turn on the gas to your house?

Tags: plumbing, furnace, gas, hot-water

During an account switch our gas got turned off. 
The account is straight now but national grid goes on coffee break from 12am sat till 7am monday and for us, enough is enough.

3 family 3 story home, I found the meter outside and you can see where a shank was removed and a valve was about 60 degrees out of place.

I made it look just like the rest, but still no gas.

Where would a second shutoff valve be?

Comment: So you'll have gas tomorrow? Why not just wait?

Comment: What you're doing might be illegal. And when the gas company does come out and see you tampered with the meter, they might very well shut it back off.

Comment: maybe against policy but they are lazy and I am fed up. The account is in perfect standing. If you aren't so st00pid enough to tell them, won't hurt anything.  I found the valve at the street. Needle nose pliers fixed the issue.

Comment: Not sure who you are calling stupid, I'm not the one who got my gas shut off.

Answer (score 1):

Call your utility. They should be able to send somebody out to turn it on, or at least explain to you why they haven't already.

The utility owns the meter, so you shouldn't be messing with it. Rest assured, they **will** hold you responsible for any damages to the meter.

Comment: as stated in the post, they completely lost our friday appt and they went on coffee break over they weekend. It's steel piping, not much you can do to it without a grinder.  I found the valve at the street.

Comment: Did you try calling them back?

Comment: Is it possible that they had a reason to leave the gas off (maybe it wasn't safe to turn it on)? Was the gas turned off because somebody didn't pay the bill?

Comment: nope. I had an idiot roommate fail to transfer the account into his name. Once the account became nameless, they shut it off. But, even after assigning a name to the account, they still could not figure out if they were going to scratch their watch or wind their @sses.